# LiipImaginebundle with a controller that renders the image

Tags: php, symfony, liipimaginebundle

I want to render an image trough a custom controller.  (Because I want to check if someone can view the image)
With LiipimagineBundle I can only assign a path directly to the images.

I put the uploads dir out of my root directory already.

Using the filter over my generated url (that renders the image perfectly when not using the imagine_filter) will not work because I can only assign the image name to the filter.

How can I solve this. Do I need to write my own Cacheresolver? Or are there any better ways solving this?

Comment: Have you looked through the docs? https://github.com/liip/LiipImagineBundle#using-the-controller-as-a-service

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Qoop for sending me in the right direction.

I skipped that part in the documentation because I thought I had to do it trough the twig function.
But indeed that is the way.